# ¿Cómo guardar elementos de una lista en un archivo txt en C#?

Tags: c#

Buen día chicos,

Actualmente estoy estudiando C# en la universidad y bueno, mi primer semana y se nos pidió hacer un pequeño programa en consola. El programa consta de tres clases:

1. Main
2. PromptGenerator
3. Entry
4. Journal

Al iniciar el programa se muestra un menú con cinco opciones:

1. Write
2. Display
3. Load
4. Save
5. Quit

Al iniciar el programa la clase **Main** muestra un menú con las cinco opciones anteriores, la opción 1 muestra en pantalla una pregunta aleatoria como: ***"Who was the most interesting person I interacted with today?"***, una respuesta podría ser ***talk to mom***, al presionar enter esa entrada se guarda en la clase **Journal** la cuál almacena una lista de entradas, hasta aquí todo bien. El problema que tengo se encuentra en el método **SaveFile()** de la clase Journal, en teoría se supone que este método debe guardar cada una de las entradas que escribí pero no me da el resultado esperado, guardo el archivo con extensión .txt y cuando posteriormente abró el archivo me aparece así:

```
Entry 
Entry
```

Lo que yo espero es que aparezcan así:

Date: 15/09/2023 - Prompt: What was the best part of my day?
read book
Date: 15/09/2023 - Prompt: Who was the most interesting person I interacted with today?
talk to mom

Adjunto el código que escribí:

Clase Main:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PromptGenerator p = new PromptGenerator();
        p._prompts.Add("Who was the most interesting person I interacted with today?");
        p._prompts.Add("What was the best part of my day?");
        p._prompts.Add("How did I see the hand of the Lord in my life today?");
        p._prompts.Add("What was the strongest emotion I felt today?");
        p._prompts.Add("If I had one thing I could do over today, what would it be?");

        Journal j = new Journal();

        int option = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to the Journal Program!");

        while (option != 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please select one of the following choices\n1. Write\n2. Display\n3. Load\n4. Save\n5. Quit");
            Console.Write("What would you like to do? ");
            option = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (option == 1)
            {     
                Random r = new Random();
                int rndIndex = r.Next(p._prompts.Count);
                string randomPrompt = p._prompts[rndIndex];
                Console.WriteLine(randomPrompt);
                string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

                DateTime theCurrenTime = DateTime.Now;
                string dateText = theCurrenTime.ToShortDateString();

                Entry entry = new Entry();
                entry._date = dateText;
                entry._prompt = randomPrompt;
                entry._userInput = userInput;

                j._entries.Add(entry);
                
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else if (option == 2)
            {
               j.DisplayEntries();
            }
            else if (option == 3)
            {

            }
            else if (option == 4)
            {
                j.SaveFile();
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Clase PromptGenerator:

```
public class PromptGenerator
{
    public List<string> _prompts = new List<string>();

    public void DisplayPrompts()
    {
        foreach(string p in _prompts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Clase Entry:

```
public class Entry
{
    public string _date;
    public string _prompt;
    public string _userInput;

    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Date: {_date} - Prompt: {_prompt}\n{_userInput}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Clase Journal:

```
using System.IO;

public class Journal
{
    public List<Entry> _entries = new List<Entry>();

    public void DisplayEntries()
    {
        foreach (Entry e in _entries)
        {
            e.Display();
        }
    }

    public void SaveFile()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the filename? ");
        string fileName = Console.ReadLine();

        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            foreach (Entry e in _entries)
            {
                outputFile.WriteLine(e);
            }            
                   
            Console.WriteLine("The file was created.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Espero mi consulta sea clara, aún me falta experiencia en C#.

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en cómo guardas la información.

Aquí precisamente:

```
foreach (Entry e in _entries)
{
     outputFile.WriteLine(e);
}
```

La función [`WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.writeline?view=net-7.0#system-io-textwriter-writeline(system-object)) llama la función `ToString` del objeto que recibe por parámetro y escribe el resultado.

Sin embargo tú clase `Entry` no posee una implementación propia de dicho método. Entonces se ejecuta la que heredada de [`Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0), que justamente devuelve el nombre de la clase.

Hay diferentes soluciones. Aquí un par:

- Crear tu propia implementación de `ToString`. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  public class Entry
  {
      ...

      public override string ToString()
      {
          return $"Date: {_date} - Prompt: {_prompt}\n{_userInput}");
      }
  }
  ```
- No imprimir directamente el objeto, sino la información que te interese. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  foreach (Entry e in _entries)
  {
      outputFile.WriteLine(e._userInput);
  }
  ```

---

Ten en cuenta que, aunque la información guardada en un archivo se vea bonita no significa que sea fácil de procesar. Normalmente es más fácil producir algo bonito a partir de algo *feo*.

Con esto quiero decir que generar el archivo es trivial, pero el proceso inverso puede ser más complicado.

Este procedimiento se conoce como [serialización](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/). Sugiero que investigues al respecto y conozcas diferentes formatos para guardar la información.

Un formato bastante simple, en especial si tienes que escribir tu propio código para procesarlo es CSV.

Comment: Mateo, muchas gracias por ser amable y aportarme tu ayuda. Tenías razón, me faltaba un método en la clase Entry y dada tu explicación del método ToString y tu ejemplo pude solucionarlo, después busque ese método en la documentación y leí: "How to override the ToString method (C# Programming Guide)". 
En cuanto a la sugerencia posterior sobre la serialización le daré una leída para ir aprendiendo más. Nuevamente muchas gracias.